# Use current form name in expression builder to create a query

Tags: forms, ms-access

I would like to refer to my current form name in the expression builder in order to create a query.

I have created the following function:

```
Public Function FormAtual()
 Dim frm As Form
 Set frm = Screen.ActiveForm
End Function
```

And then used it in the Expression Builder like that:

```
[Formulários]![FormAtual]![Lista0]
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have marked down the code using 4 leading spaces and I have removed the thanks.  Please explain what you mean by "It does not work"

Answer (score 0):

Below is something that works with a form I am using and the steps I took. This code can be simplified, but I wanted to show how the pieces fit together.

First, create the following in a Global Module

```
Public Function GetVariableValue(ctlName As String) As String
Dim sFrmName    As String
Dim sVal        As String
    ' First get the Active Form Name
    sFrmName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name

    ' Now get the value of the desired control
    sVal = Forms(sFrmName).Controls(ctlName)

    ' Display the Form/Ctl/Value
    MsgBox "Form Name: " & sFrmName & vbTab & "CtlName: " & ctlName & vbTab & "Ctl Value: " & sVal
End Function

Public Function GetFormName() As String
    GetFormName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
End Function
```

Next, use the query builder to select the Function and then specify the desired control.  i.e.

```
SELECT GetVariableValue('MyID') AS Expr1, [0_Stack].Resolved, [0_Stack].WebAddress, [0_Stack].DateAdded, [0_Stack].DateChanged, [0_Stack].MyID
FROM 0_Stack
WHERE ((([0_Stack].MyID)=GetVariableValue('MyID')));
```

Comment: I would like to be able to use (1) a variable with the current active form name which I can refer to in Expression Builder and (2) use the string selected in the list box, inside de form, called 'Lista0'.

Comment: Is your intent to have a 'canned' query that can be called by multiple forms, therefore you need to current form name? If not, I really don't understand what exactly you are trying to do. Please describe exactly how you want this to work. I understand you want to use the expression builder, and that gives the capability to get the specific control on any given form (i.e. Lista0). I'm unaware how you could invoke the builder to interface with code...

Comment: Exactly. I need a query to show info on the selected item in diferents forms. Otherwise, I would have to create a query for every form. I can invoke functions in builder. That's the reason for my creating a function that returns the current form name.

Comment: I need a way to refer to (1) the form name and (2) the string of the value selected. Two separate references.

Comment: How many forms do you want to use this with? Any chance the control names that you want to use are the same for each form? If not, can you build a 'map' of form names and field names in your Function, then just grab the value and pass it instead of passing the reference to the control?

Comment: None of these works: [Formulários]![FormAtual]![Lista0]
[Formulários](FormAtual)![Lista0]
FormAtual or FormAtual()

Comment: I get: Undefined function 'FormAtual' in expression. (Error 3085)

Comment: Did you ever change your Function to return the value??? If so, update your code in the above post. If not you need what I mentioned yesterday: "Public Function FormAtual()  As Form". And clarify "None of these work...." Where are those references and WHAT is wrong with them? Please manually create a working reference then post that so we can see.

Comment: Yes, I have changed my function. None of the possible reference combinations work in the query grid. They present the error already mentioned above, which is Undefined function 'FormAtual' in expression. (Error 3085)

Comment: I updated my answer with code and a query that worked for me. I had earlier asked if you want to use the same control name for all forms, so if you want unique names, you can either modify the code to handle, or just specify the control name when using the expression builder.

Comment: I made a few changes and got it all working, thanks to you. Saved me a lot of repeated query for each form. Tks.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are after, but to obtain the name of the active form:

```
Public Function FormAtual() As String
    FormAtual = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
End Function
```

Then, to have an expression:

```
[Formulários](FormAtual)![Lista0]
```

Comment: None of these works: [Formulários]![FormAtual]![Lista0]  //// [Formulários](FormAtual)![Lista0] ///// FormAtual ////// FormAtual() in the query grid.

Comment: I get: Undefined function 'FormAtual' in expression. (Error 3085)